# Proper Way to Redirect to controller action/view from .net core 2.1 middleware

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 2.1/Angular 6 application,  I am trying to redirect users to a static view if they are not part of a security group. I just keep getting "Error too many redirects"  when running the app.

I have a `securityMiddleWare` that is called from `Startup.cs`

```
public class ADAuthMiddleware
{

    RequestDelegate next;

    public ADAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {

        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        //check if user belongs to AD group or not
        var isAuthorized = httpContext.User.IsInRole("app.users.foo");


        // Return error if the current user is not authorized
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return;
        }

        // Jump to the next middleware if the user is authorized
        await next(httpContext);
    }

}
```

right now I have it set to return the response of 403,  this just generates the standard ugly "unauthorized page"   so i wanted a cleaner way to send users to a new view where they can get instructions on getting access... [image: access denied]

I've tried `httpContext.Response.Redirect(/controller/action)` with no luck. 
this works fine on the full .NET framework with MVC. i've found issues so far with .NET Core..  also maybe because it's running inside a `Task` instead of `IActionResult`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some logic in your middleware to ensure you don't attempt to authenticate the user again after redirecting them.

Else you'll end up in a loop of redirecting, authenticating, then redirecting because they're unauthenticated.

In the `Configure()` method of `Startup.cs` you can conditionally apply your authentication, e.g.

```
app.UseWhen(ShouldAuthenticate, appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseMiddleware<ADAuthMiddleware>();
    });
```

And define `ShouldAuthenticate` as:

```
private static bool ShouldAuthenticate(HttpContext context)
{
    var path = context.Request.Path;
    return !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/staticpage");
}
```

For redirection, you can do so in the same `Configure()` method, e.g.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/redirectpage/"); 
    }
});
```

Note that this is a simple way of achieving it and there are more "Core" ways of doing this using Identity services etc

Comment: i have the MiddleWare checking for a specific user group to access the app as a whole, doesn't this assume users coming in are authorized from the start?  it's also throwing error about "Cannot convert from bool to system.func  ?

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 sorry - I wrote that without actually checking it builds properly - define the boolean condition as a separate method and refer to it from within `UseWhen`. My understanding was that you want to redirect when they are not part of the group - they will still not be in that group when you redirect?

Comment: correct, i need to redirect on launch when they are not part of the group.. your modification builds fine,  i'm just not sure where i place the redirect now.  i need to redirect to a controller/index view ?

Comment: @Flightdoc5242 OK, have edited to show a simple redirect example - there are other more robust/configurable ways of doing so.

Comment: this works !  and it stops the redirect loop thank you !